# Adding an NSPredicate to a Core Data fetch request

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I have an entity titled Locations, which is initially populated with JSON via Alamofire. On a UIViewController with an embedded TableView and refresh button, I need to search for three specific entries in the Location entity.

Here is what I have so far:

```
//Refresh button action
    @IBAction func refreshAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let locationPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", "Bronco Stadium", "Morrison Center", "2 Morrison Center")
        let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Location> = Location.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = locationPredicate
        do {
            let results = try DatabaseController.getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
            locationList = results as [Location]
            tableView.reloadData()
        } catch {
            print("Error with request: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

results is returning with one entry: "Bronco Stadium". My hope is that it would return with the three items passed to the NSPredicate.

I apologize if this is a silly question; I'm new to Swift.

Comment: It is fetching with only one attribute because the argument is being passed only once with your `title = %@` so try this: `let locationPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(title = %@) OR (title = %@) OR (title = %@)", "Bronco Stadium", "Morrison Center", "2 Morrison Center")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, You’d want to re-write this as

```
    let locationPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@ OR title = %@ OR title = %@", "Bronco Stadium", "Morrison Center", "2 Morrison Center")
```

or if it stars to get more complex use the technique shown in the answers to [most effective way of searching using NSPredicate OR statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126766/most-effective-way-of-searching-using-nspredicate-or-statement)